# Distributing iOS app to appstore, "Asset Validation Failed"

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to distribute my iOS app to appstore using xamarin and visual studio for mac. After archiving and pressed "Sign and Distribute" I get 3 errors, all of them say "Asset validation failed" and no other information. Same error 3 times. What should I do?

I tried to distribute my iOS app and I expected it to be distributed

Comment: Please read tag descriptions before using a tag. The `distribution` tag isn't what you think.

Comment: sorry about that

Comment: How do you upload your ios ipa? You could try using Transporter app as stated in apple documentation: [Upload builds](https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/manage-builds/upload-builds). It might show you more detailed error info.

Comment: im trying to upload it using visual studio for mac and then archive to appstore

Comment: thank you, using the Transporter App I got very good error messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it doesn't show enough error info in Visual Studio, you could try using Transporter app which is recommended in Apple official document. It is easy to use and it can show warinings, errors and delivery logs

> The Transporter app for macOS is a simple and easy way to upload an app to App Store Connect for distribution on the App Store. You can view delivery progress (including warnings, errors, and delivery logs), as well as a history of past deliveries.

For more info, you could refer to [Manage builds-Upload builds](https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/manage-builds/upload-builds).

Hope it helps!